# Matching words to a pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to decrypt some text and wanted to write a Python script for that.
The way the text is encrypted is that every letter maps to a letter in the alphabet. I want to try to match large words to an English word list, because I think they have very few possibilities.

My question is, how do I check if a word matches a pattern like ABCB. So the first three letters are different, but the last letter is the same as the fourth. Were would be a possibility here. I tried using a regex, but I can't come up with a regex that does this for a word of length n. Does anybody have suggestions?

EDIT: I was asked to explain the pattern a bit more. In the example above every letter maps to a letter in the alphabet. So the A maps to a letter, the B maps to another letter, the C to another again and the last B maps to the same letter as the first B. So the pattern tells you which letters are the same and which are different. The pattern above says that the first three letters are different (A, B and C are different) and the last letter is the same as the second (Because they are both a B). 'Were' would be a solution because the A would map to w, the B would map to e and the C would map to r.

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far? Also, I am not exacly sure about what you want to do. You have a pattern ABCB and if only the last letter matches, that should be a match?

Comment: Could you give more examples of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: I don't really have much code so far. I have a list of English words I can match the regex against. The Idea is that the A maps to a letter in the alphabet, the B maps to a different letter in the alphabet, the C to another and the last B should be the same as the first B. So the pattern basicly tells you which letters are the same en which are different from each other

Comment: Though closed, there is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538299/matching-two-or-more-characters-that-are-not-the-same) in terms of regex patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some proof-of-concept code for converting a word to its pattern in your proposed format. (I haven't written it with efficiency in mind, only clarity).

```
import string

def word_to_pattern(word):
    # Stores actual-letter to pattern-placeholder mapping
    mapping = {}

    # ZYXW... so we cap pop letters starting with A from the end
    available_pattern_letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[::-1]

    pattern = []
    for letter in word.upper():
        if letter not in string.ascii_uppercase:
            # for punctuation etc
            pattern.append(letter)
            continue
        if letter not in mapping:
            # new letter we haven't seen yet in this word
            mapping[letter] = available_pattern_letters.pop()
        pattern.append(mapping[letter])
    return pattern.join("")
```

Then it's simply a matter of checking if `word_to_pattern(a) == word_to_pattern(b)`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It is indeed not very efficient, but it is definitely a method that would work. thanks!